# Creating a dynamic list within a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to create a a dynamic list with structs. Now I have the first struct where the information is stored for a person. The other struct holds the first struct like this:

[image: image, apparently I cant post image as new user]

```
Tried my best to visualize it 

employeeRegister
----------------          |-------|------| 
registerE   ------------> |city---|city--|
----------------          |London |Japan-|
numberOfemployee          |pin----|pin---|
----------------          |0101010|101010|
------|2|-------          |phone--|phone-|
                          |SAb123-|APPI20|
```

Now the problem for me is that I have coded it, and it works but not in the right way as in the image provided.

code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct personalInfo {
    char city[20];
    int pin;
    char phone[14];
};

struct employeeRegister {
    struct personalInfo registerE;
    int numberOfemployee;
};

struct employeeRegister *allocateMemory(struct employeeRegister *oldMemory, int nrOfadd);
void addding(struct employeeRegister *addressToAdd, int *nrOfadd);
void printList(struct employeeRegister *allemp, int nrOfadd);

int main(void)
{
    struct employeeRegister *employee = NULL;
    int choice;
    int nrOfaddress = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("\n1 - add employee");
        printf("\n2 - print employee list");
        printf("\n3 - exit");
        printf("\nWhat do you want to do? ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        while (getchar() != '\n');

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            employee = allocateMemory(employee, nrOfaddress);
            if (employee == NULL)
                break;
            addding(&employee[nrOfaddress], &nrOfaddress);
            break;
        case 2:
            printList(employee, nrOfaddress);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Ending!\n");
            free(employee);
            employee = NULL;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid input\n");
            break;
        }
    } while (choice != 3);
    return 0;
}

struct employeeRegister *allocateMemory(struct employeeRegister *oldMemory, int nrOfadd)
{
    struct employeeRegister *tempurary;
    if (nrOfadd == 0)
        tempurary = (struct employeeRegister *)calloc(1, sizeof(*tempurary));
    else
        tempurary = (struct employeeRegister *)realloc(oldMemory, sizeof(*tempurary)*(nrOfadd + 1));

    return tempurary;
}

void addding(struct employeeRegister *addressToAdd, int *nrOfadd)
{
    printf("City: ");
    fgets(addressToAdd->registerE.city, 20, stdin);
    addressToAdd->registerE.city[strlen(addressToAdd->registerE.city) - 1] = '\0';
    do
    {
        printf("Pin: ");
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    while ((scanf("%d", &addressToAdd->registerE.pin) != 1));
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    printf("Phone type: ");
    fgets((addressToAdd->registerE.phone), 14, stdin);
    addressToAdd->registerE.phone[strlen(addressToAdd->registerE.phone) - 1] = '\0';
    (*nrOfadd)++;
    addressToAdd->numberOfemployee = *nrOfadd;
}

void printList(struct employeeRegister *allemp, int nrOfadd)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < nrOfadd; i++)
    {
        printf("%d. %-15s%-5.1d%s\n", i + 1, allemp[i].registerE.city,
               allemp[i].registerE.pin, allemp[i].registerE.phone);
    }
}
```

When I debug the code I get this:

[image: How it looks in the debug]

```
employeeRegister                            employeeRegister
----------------           |-------|        ----------------           |-------|
registerE   ------------>  |city---|        registerE   ------------>  |city---|
 ----------------          |London |        ----------------           |London |
numberOfemployee           |pin----|        numberOfemployee           |pin----|
----------------           |0101010|        ----------------           |0101010|
------|1|-------           |phone--|        ------|2|-------           |phone--|
                           |SAb123-|                                   |SAb123-|
```

When I run the code in codeblocks, everything looks fine in the command prompt, but as you can see, it is not. How would I edit my code to achieve the result of the first image?

It is my first time posting and if there is anything wrong, let me know.

Comment: Each of your `employeeRegister` objects only holds a single `registerE`, making the `numberOfemployee` variable rather pointless. That's why you create an array of `employeeRegister`s and have your extra variable for storing that arrays length, isn't it?

Comment: As @UnholySheep says, change ```struct employeeRegister
{
   struct personalInfo* registerE;
   int numberOfemployee;
};
``` and handle the logical changes.

Comment: that is my problem I want `employeeRegister` to hold all the `registerE`in one place I dont want it to be array of `employeeRegister`. Instead I want one instance of `employeeRegister` and store everything in the `registerE`like the first image. I just dont know how to start to fix my code cuz when I run it I didnt see any problem with it at first, but later one with the debugger it showed that it was arrays of `employeeRegister`

Comment: @BoR ok will try

Comment: are you trying to get the output exactly as mentioned in the first diagram (with those `-`'s and `|`'s etc) or its just representation

Comment: _**I want one instance of `employeeRegister` and store everything in the `registerE`**_ to have mulitple records inside `registerE` , `registerE` has to be either array or pointer, so if `registerE` is a pointer is that fine?

Comment: sry for not answering right away I was in the hospital, and yes it is fine if it is a pointer. To clarify the first image is how I want it essentially to be but because of how I coded it I get a working result but it is not right solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your code is currently doing is creating an array of `struct employeeRegister`, each of which contains a single employee.

You need to change the `registerE` member of `struct employeeRegister` to a pointer so it can point to an array:

```
struct employeeRegister {
    struct personalInfo *registerE;
    int numberOfemployee;
};
```

Then create a single instances of this structure.  When you then allocate memory for more employees, you add to the memory that `registerE` points to.

The complete modified code would then be as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct personalInfo {
    char city[20];
    int pin;
    char phone[14];
};

struct employeeRegister {
    struct personalInfo *registerE;
    int numberOfemployee;
};

void allocateMemory(struct employeeRegister *allemp);
void addding(struct employeeRegister *allemp);
void printList(struct employeeRegister *allemp);

int main(void)
{
    struct employeeRegister employee = { NULL, 0 };
    int choice;
    do
    {
        printf("\n1 - add employee");
        printf("\n2 - print employee list");
        printf("\n3 - exit");
        printf("\nWhat do you want to do? ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        while (getchar() != '\n');

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            allocateMemory(&employee);
            if (employee.registerE == NULL)
                break;
            addding(&employee);
            break;
        case 2:
            printList(&employee);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Ending!\n");
            free(employee.registerE);
            employee.registerE = NULL;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid input\n");
            break;
        }
    } while (choice != 3);
    return 0;
}

void allocateMemory(struct employeeRegister *allemp)
{
    struct personalInfo *tempurary;
    tempurary = realloc(allemp->registerE, sizeof(*tempurary)*(allemp->numberOfemployee + 1));

    allemp->registerE = tempurary;
}

void addding(struct employeeRegister *allemp)
{
    printf("City: ");
    fgets(allemp->registerE[allemp->numberOfemployee].city, 20, stdin);
    allemp->registerE[allemp->numberOfemployee].city[strlen(allemp->registerE[allemp->numberOfemployee].city) - 1] = '\0';
    printf("Pin: ");
    while ((scanf("%d", &allemp->registerE[allemp->numberOfemployee].pin) != 1))
    {
        while (getchar() != '\n');
        printf("Pin: ");
    }
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    printf("Phone type: ");
    fgets((allemp->registerE[allemp->numberOfemployee].phone), 14, stdin);
    allemp->registerE[allemp->numberOfemployee].phone[strlen(allemp->registerE[allemp->numberOfemployee].phone) - 1] = '\0';
    allemp->numberOfemployee++;
}

void printList(struct employeeRegister *allemp)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < allemp->numberOfemployee; i++)
    {
        printf("%d. %-15s%-5.1d%s\n", i + 1, allemp->registerE[i].city,
               allemp->registerE[i].pin, allemp->registerE[i].phone);
    }
}
```

A few additional notes related to these changes:

- Don't cast the return value of the `malloc` family of functions, as that can hide other errors.
- `fflush(stdin)` causes undefined behavior on some implementations, so best to avoid it and use a `getchar` loop to clear the input buffer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226904/discussion-on-answer-by-dbush-creating-a-dynamic-list-within-a-struct).

Answer (score 1):

The other way to handle this is to use a 'header, data' pattern:

Start with this:

```
struct employeeRegister {
    struct personalInfo registerE;
    int numberOfemployee;
};
```

Now, change it so your registerE is the last element (since it grows):

```
struct employeeRegister {
    int numberOfemployee;
    struct personalInfo registerE;
};
```

When you allocate, use:  `malloc( sizeof(struct employeeRegister) + sizeof(struct personalInfo)*(nrOfAdd-1)`

This then allows you to loop-as-so:

```
struct personInfo * person = &allemp->registerE;
for (i = 0; i < allEmp->numberOfEmployee; i++) {
    // do something with person
    person++;
}
```

This closely matches your diagram where:

```
    +-------+--------+--------------------+
    | header|Person0 |Person1 .. PersonN  |
    +-------+--------+--------------------+
```